# Error: " ⨯ OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Clients` model once compiled." is thrown on 2nd api call of next js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I'm not sure why my Next JS App is throwing me this error. It is throwing this error not in the first api call but it is failing and giving 500 code error on the second api call

db.config.ts

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export async function connect(){
    try {
        mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!)
        const connection = mongoose.connection;

        connection.on("connected", ()=> {
            console.log('MongoDB Connected Successfully !!')
        })

        connection.on("error", (err)=> {
            console.log('MongoDB connection error. Please make sure mongodb is running')
            process.exit();
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error >>',error)
    }
}
```

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type:String,
        required: [true,'Please provide a username'],
        unique:true
    },
    email: {
        type:String,
        required: [true,'Please provide a email'],
        unique:true
    },
    password: {
        type:String,
        required: [true,'Please provide a password'],
    },
    isVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    forgetPasswordToken: String,
    forgetPasswordTokenExpiry: Date,
    verifyToken: String,
    verifyTokenExpiry: Date
})

const User = mongoose.model("Users", userSchema)

export default User;
```

The code also seems fine to me as well as there're so such error either in the console or in the terminal block